# Spark Error - Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the error below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 653 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 653.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 27294, ip-10-0-57-16.ec2.internal, executor 34): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 34 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1602898457220_0001_01_000370 on host: ip-10-0-57-16.ec2.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

My data set is 80GB
Operation i did is create some square, interaction features, so maybe double the number of columns.

I am using 20 m4.16xlarge (64CPU, 256GB, https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) instance
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = '16384'

can i do something to fix this? and why the I got OOM error even my dataset is way smaller than my instance number.

Comment: 143 usually indicates out of memory issues. Try increasing the parallelism

Comment: Thanks! which parameter of parallelism should i increase, spark.default.parallelism?

Comment: Can add post your spark code and spark submit command ??

Answer (score 1):

i increase the following two parameter and avoid the error:

```
spark.default.parallelism = '128'
spark.executor.cores = '16'
```